Set-theoretic intuition behind the costruction of coequalizers from pushouts
I'm trying to gain some intuition about the construction of coequalizers from pushouts in a general category equipped with pushouts and an initial object. For the moment, I'm playing in the category of sets and functions.
Let $ f,g\colon A\rightrightarrows B $ be functions between sets. Basically, I was wondering what the difference is between the two pushouts
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>g>> B\\
@VfVV @VVV\\
B @>>> Q_1
\end{CD}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{CD}
A\sqcup B @>[g,1_B]>> B\\
@V[f,1_B]VV @VVV\\
B @>>> Q_2
\end{CD}
$$
where $ [f,1_B]\colon A\sqcup B\to B $ and $ [g,1_B]\colon A\sqcup B\to B $ are the obvious maps induced from $ f $ and $ g $.
To me, $ Q_1 $ and $ Q_2 $ seem the same object. Indeed, in my first naive attempt at the construction of coequalizers from pushouts I sketched a copy of the first diagram in my notebbok. On the other hand, it's the second pushout that pops out in the construction I'm referring above, not the first one.

$\require{AMScd}$
The reason the first one doesn't work is that the pushout of $f : A → B$ and $g : A → C$ is (like) a quotient of $B \sqcup C$. So, in the coequalizer case, we're trying to produce a quotient of $B$ starting with $B \sqcup B$. The two $A → B$ maps tell us which $(x,y)$ pairs we want to equate, but if we just do the pushout, that will just equate $ι_1\ x$ with $ι_2\ y$.
So, the proper definition also quotients by $ι_1\ x = ι_2\ x$ for all $x$. That collapses $B \sqcup B$ back down to $B$, or if you prefer, means that $ι_1\ x = ι_2\ y$ also gives $ι_1\ x = ι_1\ y$ and so on by transitivity.
As a simple example, suppose we pick $A$ to be an initial object. It's well known that:
$$\begin{CD}
0 @>!>> B \\
@V!VV @VVV \\
B @>>> B \sqcup B
\end{CD}$$
gives the coproduct as the pushout with no equations. But the other diagram is essentially:
$$\begin{CD}
B @>id>> B \\
@VidVV @VVidV \\
B @>>id> B
\end{CD}$$
Which is what you'd expect for the quotient of $B$ by no equations.

Remember that the intuition for the pushout of the diagram $X\leftarrow U\to Y$ is to glue $X$ and $Y$ along $U$.
I made a quick sketch of your two pushout squares.
Let me know if it helped your intuition.
The first version:

The actual coequalizer:

Also remember that the coequalizer has to be a quotient of $B$. Which of the two pushouts looks like it can work?
